# Get list of domains on the network

Tags: winapi

Using the Windows API, how can I get a list of domains on my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some LDAP queries

### Here is some code I have used in a previous script (it was taken off the net somewhere, and I've left in the copyright notices)

```
' This VBScript code gets the list of the domains contained in the 
' forest that the user running the script is logged into

' ---------------------------------------------------------------
' From the book "Active Directory Cookbook" by Robbie Allen
' Publisher: O'Reilly and Associates
' ISBN: 0-596-00466-4
' Book web site: http://rallenhome.com/books/adcookbook/code.html
' ---------------------------------------------------------------

set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strADsPath =  "<GC://" & objRootDSE.Get("rootDomainNamingContext") & ">;"
strFilter  = "(objectcategory=domainDNS);"
strAttrs   = "name;"
strScope   = "SubTree"

set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
set objRS = objConn.Execute(strADsPath & strFilter & strAttrs & strScope)
objRS.MoveFirst
while Not objRS.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRS.Fields(0).Value
    objRS.MoveNext
wend
```

---

[Also a C# version](http://www.janus-net.de/2005/11/18/getting-list-of-sub-domains-from-active-directory-with-c/)

Answer (score 3):

Answered my own question:

Use the [NetServerEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370623(VS.85).aspx) function, passing in the `SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_ENUM` constant for the "servertype" argument.

In Delphi, the code looks like this:

```
<snip>
type
  NET_API_STATUS = DWORD;
  PSERVER_INFO_100 = ^SERVER_INFO_100;
  SERVER_INFO_100 = packed record
    sv100_platform_id : DWORD;
    sv100_name        : PWideChar;
end;

function NetServerEnum(  //get a list of pcs on the network (same as DOS cmd "net view")
  const servername    : PWideChar;
  const level         : DWORD;
  const bufptr        : Pointer;
  const prefmaxlen    : DWORD;
  const entriesread   : PDWORD;
  const totalentries  : PDWORD;
  const servertype    : DWORD;
  const domain        : PWideChar;
  const resume_handle : PDWORD
) : NET_API_STATUS; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

function NetApiBufferFree(  //memory mgmt routine
  const Buffer : Pointer
) : NET_API_STATUS; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

const
  MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = DWORD(-1);
  NERR_Success = 0;
  SV_TYPE_ALL  = $FFFFFFFF;
  SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_ENUM = $80000000;


function TNetwork.ComputersInDomain: TStringList;
var
  pBuffer        : PSERVER_INFO_100;
  pWork          : PSERVER_INFO_100;
  dwEntriesRead  : DWORD;
  dwTotalEntries : DWORD;
  i              : integer;
  dwResult       : NET_API_STATUS;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.Clear;

  dwResult := NetServerEnum(nil,100,@pBuffer,MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                            @dwEntriesRead,@dwTotalEntries,SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_ENUM,
                            PWideChar(FDomainName),nil);

  if dwResult = NERR_SUCCESS then begin
    try
      pWork := pBuffer;
      for i := 1 to dwEntriesRead do begin
        Result.Add(pWork.sv100_name);
        inc(pWork);
      end;  //for i
    finally
      NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
    end;  //try-finally
  end  //if no error
  else begin
    raise Exception.Create('Error while retrieving computer list from domain ' +
                           FDomainName + #13#10 +
                           SysErrorMessage(dwResult));
  end;
end;
<snip>
```